# Outlook add ins saveAsync is not returning itemid anymore in OWA

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

In Outlook Appointment Compose mode

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (result) {
                       app.showNotification(result.value);
        });
```

Is not returning the itemid anymore, but rather some strange string (ex: CLCID:M9_1473129000000_1473130800000__Busy_false_false) and then the whole addin and appointment dialog is closing.
Seems to be a bug introduced by a OWA update? Works fine in the Outlook desktop version.
Is there any workarounds to save an item and get the itemid?

Comment: Thanks for the report. Known issue - we're fixing ASAP.

Comment: No known workaround, unfortunately - will need to wait for the fix which is coming.

Comment: Just got exactly the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I can surely say appointment dialog is being closed and i can replicate it on my mailbox, but id was being return. Anyways, this id is of no use because appointment is being closed after 2-3 seconds.

However, strangely for one of my colleague its not happening, but everyone else has this issue.

Let me know if you found something to get it rsolved

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue has been fixed by Microsoft, as i can no longer see appointment windows is closed and is returning itemid