# SaveAsync in outlook 365 javascript api

Tags: ms-office, office365, outlook-addin, office-js

We have an office addin for outlook in the store which worked perfectly until recent. On using the save-async the appointment window isclosed after 2 seconds with no errors and no trace.

Before the saveasync we populate subject and body with information and the information appears for like 1 second before the window closes.

The issue does only appear in the owa (webversion of outlook).

Comment: This is a known issue. We're currently working on getting a fix out.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue. I have asked this question on MSDN devloper froum. but no response as of now and i have seen other people have similar issue as well.

[Outlook add ins saveAsync is not returning itemid anymore in OWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351601/outlook-add-ins-saveasync-is-not-returning-itemid-anymore-in-owa/39552560#39552560)

I have now raised a support incident directly with Microsoft as well and are in discussion with them. Will update here once i got any reply from microsoft.

Comment: can you please update Microsoft reply on your support request?

Comment: @ManojPatil, i believe this issue has been fixed by Microsoft and is no longer replicable in outlook 365 web. i will try to find out if Microsoft published any incident report and will link with this post. Thanks